# Fontawesome icon isn't showing up

Tags: font-awesome, sveltekit

I'm developing a website using svelte & svelte-kit. Used the npm commands to install the following packages into my project (taken from the dependencies section in my packages.json):

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1"
```

This is the same way I installed and used fontawesome icons in my previous projects and it always worked.

I'm trying to use an icon through `<i class="fa-solid fa-bars"`, however no icons are ever showing, no matter which one I try. I tried applying some css to the icon to diagnose the issue, the holy solid border and the icon had no width, no height. I forcefully increased those and there's just no icon, nowhere.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? When checking the markup in your browser, does it show that the fonts are loaded?

Comment: @NicoHaase I haven't really done anything because I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I checked the Fontawesome docs but they only discuss very common issues like missing characters or using pro icons instead of free which is not the case here. When I inspect the element, there's no styling, compared to my other website where there are like 10 lines of css for an icon (none applied by me manually)